# What is the logic behind the equation of the diagonal of chess?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, math, logic, backtracking

Hi everyone I am trying to solve the problem of N  queen  with the backtracking algorithm  for getting solutions but the problem here is understanding the equation of the diagonal and how we get it(d1 & d2 in image)
thanks.

[image: chess]

Comment: Diagonals are lines on the plane with gradient +1 or -1.  Then for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879279/finding-the-equation-of-2d-lines

Comment: Hey, thank you  for your response, if u can explain more because I don't get the same equation of d1 and d2

Comment: Perhaps add into your question what you get as the equations for d1 and d2? I note that in the picture, the columns (and presumably the rows) are indexed from 1 rather than the more typical 0, and perhaps that's the difference?

Comment: Start with 1 and not with  0 because in the d2 equation if queen  in the row 0 and column 0  d2 < 0  and that is not correct counter to use 1 we get d2=1